# Inequality with conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, conditional-expectation

What I want to prove is that: 
$$E\left[(X-E[X|\mathscr G])^2\right] \le E\left[(X-E[X])^2\right].$$

I tried with the following and I would like to know if it is correct. The inequality become:

$$E[X^2]+E^2[X]-2E[XE[X|\mathscr G]]\le E[X^2]-E^2[X]$$
next step:
$$E^2[X]\le E[XE[X|\mathscr G]]$$
that by definition of conditional expectation become:
$$E^2[X]\le E[XX]=E[X^2].$$

Did I wrongly apply the definition of conditional expectation or the tower property?

Comment: $\mathscr G$ is any sigma algebra yes.

Comment: no, it is a random variable defined as Z=E[X|$\mathscr G$] that is $\mathscr G$ measurable

Comment: Didn't check your proof, however if you wish to prove the statement, the standard approach is to add and subtract $E[X]$ from left hand side of the inequality and do the square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=X\cdot E[X\mid \mathcal G]$. Then $E[Y\mid\mathcal G]=(E[X\mid \mathcal G])^2$ hence $$\tag{*}E[Y]=E[E[Y\mid\mathcal G]]=E\left[(E[X\mid \mathcal G])^2\right]\geqslant \left(E[E[X\mid \mathcal G]]\right)^2,$$
by Jensen's inequality.

The equality $E[E^2[X|\mathscr G]] = E^2[X]$ may not hold hence the reduction of the wanted inequality in the opening post should read 
$$
E[X^2]+E\left[E[X\mid\mathcal G]^2\right]-2E[XE[X|\mathscr G]]\le E[X^2]-E^2[X]
$$
and by simplifying, 
$$ E\left[E[X\mid\mathcal G]^2\right]+E^2[X] \le 2E[XE[X|\mathscr G]].
$$
This follows from (*) and the remark that by Jensen's inequality, 
$$ E\left[E[X\mid\mathcal G]^2\right]
\geqslant \left(E\left[E[X\mid\mathcal G]\right]\right)^2=\left(E[X]\right)^2.$$

Comment: This proof is perfect, assuming that my previous computation was right. in particular I would like to ask for this step: $E[E^2[X|\mathscr G]] = E^2[X]$. I'm always more sure that is wrong, so also my proof in the first row was wrong, right?

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to address your issue.